# Number of Conv2d Layers and Filters for Small Image Classification Task

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network

If I'm working with a dataset where I have ~100,000 training images and ~20,000 validation images, each of size 32 x 32 x 3, how does the size and the dimensions of my dataset affect the number of `Conv2d` layers I have in my CNN? My intuition is to use fewer `Conv2d` layers, 2-3, because any more than 3 layers will be working with parts of the image that are too small to gain relevant data from.

In addition, does it make sense to have layers with a large number of filters, >128? My thought is that when dealing with small images, it doesn't make sense to have a large number of parameters.

Comment: My understanding is that (behind the curtains) most deep learning researchers are just trying things. Also, the entropy/complexity of your image set is a significant variable in what size of network will do the job. As far as I know, there are no rules of thumb at all regarding how to estimate the appropriate network size; it is 100% empirical.  

It's been suggested that estimating the required network-size requires knowledge of the solution, which is similar to the halting problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have the exact input size like the images in Cifar10 and Cifar100 just have a look what people tried out.

In general you can start with something like a ResNet18. Also I don't quite understand why you say

> because any more than 3 layers will be working with parts of the image that are too small to gain relevant data from.

As long as you don't downsample using something like max pooling or a conv with padding 1 and stride 2. The size of 32x32 will be the same and only the number of channels will change depending on the network.

Designing networks is almost always at looking what did other people do and what worked for them and starting from there. You almost never want to do it from scratch on your own, since the iteration cycles are just to long and models released by researches from Google, Facebook ... had way more resources then you will ever have to find something good.